# How is Enoch's story relevant to the rest of Wise Blood?

Tags: character-analysis, flannery-oconnor, wise-blood

I understand Enoch's character arc somewhat, some vague notion of missing human connection and having a more animal nature, and the parallel between putting on the gorilla costume and the Biblical Enoch being taken up into heaven.

But as far as I can tell, this has very little impact on the "main" story, except for the scene when Enoch delivers the mummy.

I see some parallels between Enoch and Haze in that they're isolated, and they have... some sort of change at the end?

What does this character add to the book?